# Reference for Azhwars in english/ Hindi

Tags: sri-vaishnava, reference-request, vishishtadvaita

The Azhwars are a group of 12 vaishnava saints from Tamizh Nadu, I want to know if there is any group of texts which covers the various aspects of their life. Has any traditional scholar before Shri Vedanta Deshika has written about them in Sanskrit, or is there translation of the tamizh works in English? I want to get a comprehensive picture of the Azhwars from the traditional viewpoint, thus modern day papers which try to date all of them in A.D. are less of the priority.

P.S : I don't know Tamizh

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can find it in Divyasuri Charitram by Garudavahana. There is a Sanskrit to Hindi version available. I don’t think it is before Vedanta Desikan but. There are two three more books but can’t place the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are English translations of their works.

- *[Philosophy and Theistic Mysticism of the Alvars](https://archive.org/details/philosophyandtheisticmysticismofthealvarssmschariocr)*. This explores the divine experiences the Alvars expressed and important concepts in their work.
- *[Hymns for the Drowning](https://archive.org/details/hymnsfordrowning0000namm/mode/2up)*. A translation of Nammalvar's hymns.
- *[Musings on Andal's Tiruppavai](https://archive.org/details/musingsonsaintandaltiruppavaidrvssampathkumaracharya2002ocr)*. A translation of hymns by Andal.
- *[The Secret Garland: Āṇṭāḷ’s Tiruppāvai and Nācciyār Tirumoḻi](https://archive.org/details/secretgarlandantalstiruppavaiandnacciyartirumoliarchanavenkatesan_380_k)*. Another translation of Andal's Tiruppavai as well as another of her works, the Nachiyar Tirumoḻi.
- *[Hymns of the Alvars: in Praise of Lord Srinivasa](https://ebooks.tirumala.org/downloads/hymns_of_the_alvars.pdf)*. A compilation of different verses from various works by the Alvars concerned with praising Vishnu.
- *[Hymns of the Alvars](https://archive.org/details/hymnsofthealvars020204mbp/page/n39/mode/2up)*. Another translation of various works by the Alvars.

Comment: I am not looking for the translation of their works, rather I am looking for their life story like who they were, when did they take up the avatara etc

Comment: There's a little bit about that starting from p. 11 of the first book I linked: https://archive.org/details/philosophyandtheisticmysticismofthealvarssmschariocr/page/n27/mode/2up

Comment: Thanks for the response